# How to combat nested/conditional subscriptions using RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

This problem concerns an Angular front-end with nested RxJS subscriptions. Here's a model of what this code currently resembles:

```
this.apiServices.getData(arg1)
    .subscribe({
        next: data => {
            this.randFunc1();

            if (this.isCond()) {
                this.apiServices.getDataMapper(arg2)
                    .subscribe({
                        next: mapperData => {                          
                            this.randFunc2();
                            this.apiServices.getDataTemp(arg3)
                                .subscribe({
                                    next: tempData => {
                                        this.randFunc3();
                                    },
                                    error: error => {
                                        this.handleError(``);
                                    }
                                });
                        },
                        error: error => {
                            this.handleError(``);
                        }
                    });

            } else {
                this.apiServices.getDocData(arg4)
                    .subscribe({
                        next: docData => {
                            reassignment = true;
                            this.randFunc4();
                        },
                        error: error => {
                            this.handleError(``);
                        }
                    });
            }
        },
        error: error => {
            this.handleError(``);
        }
    });
```

So far, I've tried piping this using tap/switchMap.  I'm unsure if the following is right, but here's what I have:

```
this.apiServices.getData(args1).pipe(
    tap(data=> {
        this.randFunc1();
    }),
    switchMap(() => {
        if (this.isCond()) {

        } else {
            return this.apiServices.getDocData(arg4)
        }
    })
).subscribe();
```

As you can see, I'm halting the given (and currently coherent) code with the initial if/else.  Each route carries code galore—some of which includes other subscriptions.  I've considered nesting pipes, but I don't understand how/why that would work.  Is this, at least, a good start?

I'd appreciate any help with this (especially explanations on which RxJS operators to use and why).

Comment: Here's a video that may be a good place to start (nested subscriptions): https://youtu.be/KiJ-e5QuWe4 And this one might help (mergeMap vs concatMap vs switchMap): https://youtu.be/RSf7DlJXoGQ

Comment: The second video helped a lot.  I've always been confused on when to best use each of those three operators, and no other resource has helped me understand them.  Thank you very much for the links.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a declarative approach and simplify your pipeline that way. Is it correct to assume that the `this.isCond()` is dependent on the result of the first http get?

You could try something like this:

```
    primaryData$ = this.apiServices.getData(args1).pipe(
      tap(data=> {
            this.randFunc1();
      })
    );


    mapperData$ = this.primaryData$.pipe(
      switchMap((p) => {
        if (this.isCond()) {
          return ...          
        }
    }))

    docData$ = this.primaryData$.pipe(
      switchMap((p) => {
        if (!this.isCond()) {
          return ...          
        }
    }))
```

The basic idea is that we use declared variables to define the Observables. This has the side benefit in that you can use the async pipe to subscribe instead of needing to call `subscribe()` directly.

The first declaration is getting your primary data. The other declarations then respond to emissions from the first declaration to get the remaining data

I have a code example you can try out and run here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-large-pipeline-deborahk-sqcucg

Comment: Listen to Deborah.

Comment: Yes, the isCond() function returns a boolean value that depends on a field from the getData() function's returned JSON.  I have another question based on your response.  I need an additional observable that would normally be nested within the getDataMapper() API call (your mapperData$).  Would I simply write something like

`templateData$ = this.mapperData$.pipe(...)`

, or would I pipe within mapperData$?

Comment: In general terms, either would work. Separating the calls into separate Observables can make the code a little easier to read/work with because each operation is basically separate.